# Number \newtheorem Based on Previous Instance

Tags: amsmath

I have used `\newtheorem` to define a class.  I want to modify a previous instance of the class to present a slight variation.  (A similar, but different, example is using a previous equation to number the current one.)  Here is an example of the output I would like:

Assumption 1.  An assumption.

Assumption 1'.  A similar assumption.

I have tried using `\tag` with no success.  Here is an example of my failed attempts:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}


\begin{document}

\begin{assumption}
    \label{a1}
    An assumption.
\end{assumption}

\begin{assumption}
   \label{a1'}
   A similar assumption.
   \tag{\ref{a1}'}
\end{assumption}

\end{document}
```

My main interest is not in getting `\tag` to work, but in finding some (preferably simple) way to get numbering like this.  Any help would be appreciated.